# how to make services be dependent on each other

Tags: windows

I know the SC commmand using command promt, but the dependencies of the service solely rely on one, How can you make them depend on each other? For instance if Service A would stop then Service B would also stop, vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run

```
sc config ServiceA depend= ServiceB
```

and then

```
sc config ServiceB depend= ServiceA
```